# Adding one JOIN statement changes the value of precedent sum

Tags: mysql

I have this query in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f383/5) which gives the correct values

But when I add one left joined table the result changes(I tried with right and inner join same bad result) and it's there in  this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f383/4)

What I miss in this query when adding stockdata?

There is 3 tables defmatiere, ingredients and stockdata

When I use this query:

```
SELECT dm.nom,SUM(IF(dm.id=ig.matid AND ig.matcuisine= 3,ig.qty,0)) AS bisused
FROM ingredient AS ig
LEFT JOIN DefMatiere AS dm ON ig.matid=dm.id AND ig.matcuisine=3 
WHERE dm.id=ig.matid AND dm.type=1 GROUP BY dm.nom
```

I get the corrects sums

But When I use this query

```
SELECT dm.nom,SUM(IF(dm.id=ig.matid AND ig.matcuisine= 3,ig.qty,0)) AS bisused,
SUM(DISTINCT IF(dm.id=sd.matid, sd.quantite,0)) AS bisbought
FROM ingredient AS ig 
LEFT JOIN DefMatiere AS dm ON ig.matid=dm.id AND ig.matcuisine=3 
LEFT JOIN StockData AS sd ON sd.matid=dm.id
WHERE dm.id=ig.matid AND dm.type=1 GROUP BY dm.nom
```

The sum of bisused is doubled the rest is correct

Comment: Please update the question itself to include relevant data

Comment: Can Stock Data and Ingredients be joined on a value?

Comment: Yes I get the sums of Ingredients used and bought. But when I add the lines (JOIN statement of Stockdata) the sum of used is doubled. When using only Defmatiere and ingredient (JOINED) there is no probleme data retrieved is correct.

Comment: The data from Stock and Ingredients are being cross joined because they don't have a common field

Comment: matid is the common field in Stock and ingredients which does not contain the name of the products but the id of products in both table. I retrieve the names of products from DefMatiere by matid